# Retrofit 2, GSON and custom parsing

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit2, Gson for fetching and parsing data. For now, I have got below response for which creating POJO classes are not working -

```
[
  {
    "state": "Tripura",
    "districtData": [
      {
        "district": "Gomati",
        "confirmed": 1,
        "lastupdatedtime": "",
        "delta": {
          "confirmed": 0
        }
      },
      {
        "district": "North Tripura",
        "confirmed": 1,
        "lastupdatedtime": "",
        "delta": {
          "confirmed": 0
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "state": "Nagaland",
    "districtData": [
      {
        "district": "Dimapur",
        "confirmed": 1,
        "lastupdatedtime": "",
        "delta": {
          "confirmed": 0
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I am not able to get proper data out of this response. I have already read about custom JSON parsing for retrofit (eg - https://medium.com/@andersonk/retrofit-2-custom-deserializer-for-unwrapping-properties-8cb8b2ec901e ) but it is not working for me.
Also, questions related to this in StackOverflow are related to Specific Json response than generic.

Please provide useful link / Solution for the same

Comment: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess, that since the response is the list, that is what is causing your error.

If you declare your POJO something like this

```
public class ResponseData {

@SerializedName("state")
@Expose
public String state;
@SerializedName("districtData")
@Expose
public List<DistrictDatum> districtData = null;

}
```

Then you need to change parameter of your Call object inside retrofit to look something like this:

```
Call<ArrayList<ResponseData> loadDataFromApi();
```

Edit: `DistrictDatum` Also must be a class with field from API.

Comment: Thanks a Lot.I was missing Call<ArrayList<ResponseData> loadDataFromApi();..as I am taking directly data but not as List of data

Answer (score 1):

Please check your POJO class

```
 -----------------------------------com.example.Delta.java-----------------------------------

    package com.example;

    import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
    import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

    public class Delta {

    @SerializedName("confirmed")
    @Expose
    private Integer confirmed;

    public Integer getConfirmed() {
    return confirmed;
    }

    public void setConfirmed(Integer confirmed) {
    this.confirmed = confirmed;
    }

    }
    -----------------------------------com.example.DistrictDatum.java-----------------------------------

    package com.example;

    import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
    import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

    public class DistrictDatum {

    @SerializedName("district")
    @Expose
    private String district;
    @SerializedName("confirmed")
    @Expose
    private Integer confirmed;
    @SerializedName("lastupdatedtime")
    @Expose
    private String lastupdatedtime;
    @SerializedName("delta")
    @Expose
    private Delta delta;

    public String getDistrict() {
    return district;
    }

    public void setDistrict(String district) {
    this.district = district;
    }

    public Integer getConfirmed() {
    return confirmed;
    }

    public void setConfirmed(Integer confirmed) {
    this.confirmed = confirmed;
    }

    public String getLastupdatedtime() {
    return lastupdatedtime;
    }

    public void setLastupdatedtime(String lastupdatedtime) {
    this.lastupdatedtime = lastupdatedtime;
    }

    public Delta getDelta() {
    return delta;
    }

    public void setDelta(Delta delta) {
    this.delta = delta;
    }

    }
    -----------------------------------com.example.Example.java-----------------------------------

    package com.example;

    import java.util.List;
    import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
    import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

    public class Example {

    @SerializedName("state")
    @Expose
    private String state;
    @SerializedName("districtData")
    @Expose
    private List<DistrictDatum> districtData = null;

    public String getState() {
    return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
    }

    public List<DistrictDatum> getDistrictData() {
    return districtData;
    }

    public void setDistrictData(List<DistrictDatum> districtData) {
    this.districtData = districtData;
    }

    }
```